# Why did 'Trinethra' organization choose their office under Tailorman which is easily accessible?

Tags: plot-explanation, goodachari

In the Telugu movie *[Goodachari](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7758160/)*, the internal security organization 'Trinetra' is setup under a clothes store 'Tailorman' which is quite accessible to outside people. Why would some organization as high profile, secretive as this choose a place like that? The terrorists could easily see/surveil Arjun from outside the store and the heroine almost came to the entrance of the 'entrance'.

Couldn't they have set up their office in a more secure location? Even the basement of a software company (id checks to enter, no external vigilance) sounds more secretive than under a clothes shop.

Comment: I don't think they have thought it through. The idea is based on British movie *Kingsman*.